# Connect to OrientDB with the Gremlin javascript driver

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm struggling to find an example using the current gremlin javascript driver with OrientDB. I can't get it to connect to OrientDB (already using the tinkerpop enabled version).

My sample code looks like this:

```
const gremlin = require("gremlin")
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection

const graph = new gremlin.structure.Graph()
const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/demodb'))

g.V().toList().then(function(data) {
   console.log(data)
}).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(err)
})
```

Does someone have any experience using those together? Thanks

Comment: which problem do you have? Were you able to run the GremlinServer embedded in OrientDB TP3 Edition ?

Comment: Yes, and I was able to connect to the db via the gremlin console, but not from the gremlin javascript driver.

Comment: do you have a gist to reproduce this? Thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zoltangbereczky/8baab215d43a73dd8939c929ebbee331 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect OrientDB trough Gremlin try this:

```
Local -> gremlin> g = new OrientGraph("plocal:db_path/nomeDB")

In-Memory -> gremlin> g = new OrientGraph("memory:nomeDB")

Remote -> gremlin> g = new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/nomeDB")
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thank you Michela! I was able to connect to the db via the gremlin console, however I couldn't get the gremlin javascript driver to work. [npmjs.com/package/gremlin] I updated my original question with sample code.

Comment: this not works for javascript. Only for the console.

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little bit. Gremlin Javascript driver does not support GraphSON3

https://github.com/jbmusso/gremlin-javascript/issues/109

Add this to your server.yaml serializer configuration in order to add support for v2

```
- { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.orientdb.io.OrientIoRegistry] }}
```

Then it should work

Comment: The gremlin npm package now points to the official TinkerPop3 javascript driver (jbnusso's verison was deprecated), which has GraphSON3 support. 
However, I tried it with the v2 serializer and got the same result: `Vertex { id: '#33:0', label: '', properties: undefined }`

Comment: Is the package available on NPM support GraphSON3?

Comment: I get this when using gremlin javascript 3.2.9  against Gremlin Server 3.3.1

error Error: Server error (no request information): Invalid OpProcessor requested [null] (499)

Comment: According to the git repo [https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/master/gremlin-javascript/src/main/javascript/gremlin-javascript/lib], it got GraphSON3 support 2 months ago. However, the defaultMimeType is v2, so you have to provide an options object when initiating the new DriverRemoteConnection or overwrite the defaultMimeType in driver-remote-connection.js with "application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json" I guess.

Comment: I've run your test with the V3 mimeType

const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', {
 mimeType : "application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json"
}))

I still  get an empty array as response even if vertices are on the server. I've avoided OrientDB and used gremlin-server-classic.yaml

Comment: Are you able to make it work with gremlin-server-classic.yaml?

Comment: No, but it connects if used with gremlin-server-modern.yaml
It still returns an empty array.

Comment: I was able to connect with OrientDB as a graph implementation. Which problem do you have in connection?

Comment: @wolf4ood Do you still remember how you did that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import * as gremlin from 'gremlin';
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;

const authenticator = new gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(<db username>, <db password>);
const traversal = gremlin.process.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

const g = traversal().withRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', {
      authenticator: authenticator
    }));
```

Notice the `/gremlin` in the url, not `/demodb`.
To point to `demodb` or another database modify the `demodb.properties` file in the `config` folder from OrientDB.

If you want you can create another properties file, just remember to point to it in the `gremlin-server.yaml` file.